# Доступ к wifi для конкретного устройства

Tags: wifi, маршрутизация, mikrotik, wlan

Как будет выглядеть системный скрипт для winbox, Который должен будет включить WLAN для конкретного устройства? Знаю лишь такой код `interface wireless enable wlan1`, но насколько я знаю она распространяется на все устройства. Возможно ли сделать нечто подобное, но лишь для одного конкретного устройства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снимаете галочку `default authenticate` в настройках `wlan1`. Потом на вкладке `Access list` добавляете нужное устройсво по МАС-у.

Если нужно запретить какойто МАС, то оставляем галку на месте, а в `Access list` пишем маки и убираем галочку там.

Answer (score 1):

Включать Wi-Fi для конкретного устройства не получится, это общий сетевой интерфейс, но при помощи фаервола можно ограничить доступ для отдельных устройств, подключённых через Wi-Fi.

Если нужно разрешить всем, кроме устройства с MAC `00:00:00:00:00:00`:

```
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=forward src-mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 in-interface=wlan1
```

Если нужно запретить всем, кроме устройства с MAC `00:00:00:00:00:00`:

```
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=forward src-mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 in-interface=wlan1
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=forward in-interface=wlan1
```

Comment: Ответ не соответсвует вопросу.

Comment: @eri, я сразу сказал, что реализовать так, как хочет автор, не получится, поэтому предложил альтернативное решение.

Comment: всё получится, Вам просто надо немного подучить матчасть.